# Displaying selected sensor values in a List View realtime

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an application which has following functionality.

1. User selects the sensors which are available in the device.
2. The UI shows the selected Sensor Name and readings in a Listview.(Values update real time)

I have a custom class to store sensor data (SenseData) and custom view to display sensor name and readings.

I wrote a custom Adaptor class which takes a list of SenseData to populate a list view component in my activity.

What I want to do is, take a list of SenseData.

I'm trying this for about a week and didn't get any solutions.
I'll be very grateful if someone can give me a hint.

EDITED:

**Adaptor class**

```
public class SensorAdaptor extends BaseAdapter{

Context context;
List<SenseData> senseData;

public SensorAdaptor(Context context, List<SenseData> senseData){
    this.context = context;
    this.senseData = senseData;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return senseData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return senseData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view;

    if(convertView == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_sensor, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.senseName);
        holder.data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.senseReading);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    SenseData data = senseData.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(data.getSensorName());
    holder.data.setText(data.getSensorValues());
    return null;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    TextView name;
    TextView data;
}
}
```

**onSensorChanged method**

```
    @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    this.event = event;
//SupportedSensors contains the predefined sensor types. sensor is a SenseData type object
    Intent filter = new Intent(new 
SupportedSensors().getType(event.sensor.getType()));
    filter.putExtra("value", event.values[0]);
    ctx.sendBroadcast(filter); //ctx is the context
}
```

Then I receive broadcasts with filters which have sensor names as action. But I couldn't find out a way to return a list in Broadcast receiver. SenseData class has setters and getters to set and get data.

```
public class SensorBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    switch(intent.getAction()){
        case "accelerometer":
            System.out.println("Accelerometer");
            break;
        case "gyroscope":
            System.out.println("Gyroscope");
            break;
        case "gravity":
            System.out.println("Gravity");
            break;
        case "proximity":
            System.out.println("Proximity");
            break;
        case "pressure":
            System.out.println("Pressure");
            break;
        case "light":
            System.out.println("Light");
            break;
        case "magnetometer":
            System.out.println("Magnetometer");
            break;
        case "rotation":
            System.out.println("Rotation Vector");
            break;
    }

}
```

The receiver is registered in the Activity

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("accelerometer");
    SensorBroadcastReceiver receiver = new SensorBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

I can add a `List<SenseData> sensordatalist` to `SensorBroadcastReceiver` but how to get values real time?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, elaborate your question, show examples on what you want to do, what have you tried, and the code you already tried... then we can give pointers on what direction you could go.

Comment: Hi Bonatti, I added the necessary code of my project. Thanks

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: please give up point to answer if you getting help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using the following method....

1. Create a class `RealTimeSensorReader` which reads the sensors.

   ```
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

   RealTimeSensor realTimeSensor = new RealTimeSensor();
   realTimeSensor.setName(AvailableSensors.getType(event.sensor.getType()).toUpperCase());
   realTimeSensor.setValueX(event.values[0]+"");
   realTimeSensor.setValueY(event.values[1]+"");
   realTimeSensor.setValueZ(event.values[2]+"");

   System.out.println(values);

   TempStore.sensor.put(AvailableSensors.getType(event.sensor.getType()), realTimeSensor);

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction("sensor");
   context.sendBroadcast(intent);

   adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();}
   ```
2. Define a separate class `TempStore` which contains two static fields
   a `ConcurrentHashMap` and a `LinkedList` which are for store sensor
   data and to populate the ListView separately.

   ```
   public class TempStore {

   public static ConcurrentMap<String, RealTimeSensor> sensor = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   public static ArrayList<RealTimeSensor> realTimeSensors = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
3. In onSensorChanged method I put the sensor values with the sensor
   name as the key to the HashMap. And send a broadcast whenever a
   sensor is changed.
4. Created a broadcast listener which listen to that broadcast, and
   clear the current LinkedList values and add the values set of the
   HashMap.

   ```
   TempStore.realTimeSensors.clear();
   TempStore.realTimeSensors.addAll(TempStore.sensor.values());
   ```

What I need to know is whether this method is correct or wrong.

Thank you very much