# Updating the values of an Array List efficiently - Java

Tags: java

Are there any way to update an ArrayList efficiently. My data set changes at a rate of nearly 1000 times per second. Or are there any specific data structure which can handle updates in such a rate?

Related to my [question about android sensors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753523/displaying-selected-sensor-values-in-a-list-view-realtime)

**EDIT:**

```
 Set<String> selectedSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(SenseConstants.SELECTED_SENSORS_BY_USER, null);

 TempStore.sensors.addAll(TempStore.sensor.values());
    if(TempStore.realTimeSensors.size()>0){
        for(RealTimeSensor s : TempStore.realTimeSensors){
            if(selectedSet.contains(s.getName())){
                TempStore.realTimeSensors.add(TempStore.realTimeSensors.indexOf(s), TempStore.sensor.get(s.getName()));
            }
        }

    }else{
       for(String s : selectedSet){
           TempStore.realTimeSensors.add(TempStore.sensor.get(s));
       }
    }
```

TempStore has static ConcurrentHashMap and an ArrayList. In HashMap sensor values will be stored as they are read. The ArrayList is used to populate android ListView.

I need to replace the current value with new value.

Comment: What do you mean by update? Add elements? Remove elements? Set elements? Add to the end or to beginning? Show us the current (probably inefficient) code and we will see if it could be done in more efficient manner.

Comment: use a map, with key = sensor name (maybe)..

Comment: I will suggest using a self balancing binary tree In this case similar to how database indexing works.
In java collections a tree set or map depending on your need are useful

I'd say array can be better replaced with treeset.
I will sugges tusing a self balancing binary tree In this case similar to how databases work.
In java collections a tree set or map depending on your need are useful

I'd say array can be better replaced with treeset.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html